# While loop logic clarification + harmonic series

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

This is my code for finding the sum of a harmonic series of 1/n. I want it to stop when the sum is greater than or equal to 15, but the code cannot run. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong? It seems to follow the correct while loop structure. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int divisor = 1;
    int sum = 1;
    while ((sum <= 15) && (divisor >=1))
    {
        sum = sum + (1/divisor);
        divisor++;
    }
    cout << "You need " << divisor << " terms to get a sum <= 15" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps becuse `1/divisor` is an integer divide, which given your code will only ever give `sum` with a value of `1`?

Comment: What do you mean "cannot run"? Explain the exact behavior you're seeing. Compile-time error? Run-time crash? Run-time hang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is actually running. However, your `sum` variable is of type `int`, and so is `divisor`.

1 (an `int`) / divisor (also an `int`) will return 1 or 0. This is because you are doing integer division. `1/1 == 1`. However, `1/2 == 0`, `1/3 == 0`, etc... To solve this, cast divisor to double:

`(1 / (double)divisor)`

So that solves the issue of that segment returning only 1 or 0. However, you will still gain a sum of 1 as `sum` is of type `int`. Attempting to assign a `double` to an `int` variable will result in a truncation, or floor rounding. Sum will add the first `1`, but it will remain `1` indefinitely after that. In order to solve this, change the type of `sum` to `double`.

Your assignment of `sum = 1;` is a logical error. Your result will be 1 higher than it should be. Your output statement is also mistaken... It should be...

`cout << "You need " << divisor << " terms to get a sum > 15" << endl;`

In addition, the condition of `divisor >= 1` is needless... It is always greater than or equal to one because you assign it as 1 and are incrementing... If you do want a sum that is `>= 15`, change the `while` condition to...

`while (sum < 15)`

Your code should look like this...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int divisor = 1;
    double sum = 0; //Changed the type to double and assigned 0 rather than 1

    while (sum <= 15) //While condition shortened...
    {
        sum = sum + (1 / (double)divisor); //Added type cast to divisor
        divisor++;
    }

    //cout statement adjusted...
    cout << "You need " << divisor << " terms to get a sum > 15" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josiah! I'm very new to programming in general so sorry for the noob question. Thanks again for the very detailed debugging-it's one of the few ones I can actually understand. I'll pass on the favor to someone else when I get better :)

Comment: No problem! I could tell you were a newbie programmer... Thats why I was willing to go into such detail haha. And you should mark my answer as the solution... ;D

Comment: sure! Thanks for the tip. New to the stack as well ;)